# Any example of ASIHTTPREQUEST used ON WORDPRESS POST?

Tags: iphone, wordpress, ipad, asihttprequest

Who can post an example of asihttprequest used on wordpress post?

*EDIT*
I want to use asihttprequest for get in one array obeject all post and relative image of my homepage http://www.notizie-informatiche.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get better responses if you at least give it a shot first. This isn't a "code this for me for free" site.

I wrote an example of an ASIHTTPRequest here: [iPhone ASIHTTP - Distinguishing between API calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780805/iphone-asihttp-distinguishing-between-api-calls/3781159#3781159)

It's not specifically a wordpress post (whatever "used ON WORDPRESS POST" means, I can think of at least two ways to interpret that), but if you figure out what the web browser is doing when the request you want to make gets made, it's simple to replicate in ASI.

Comment: Thanks fot the answer, I want to use asihttprequest for get in one array obeject all post and relative image of my homepage http://www.notizie-informatiche.com/

Comment: Well, if you figure out how to ask Wordpress for that, making ASI request it is pretty simple.

Comment: Yep, agree with Dan. It's probably a good idea to ask another question asking only how you retrieve the information you want from wordpress. Once you know how to get the information out of wordpress we can help you figure out how to do that on the iphone.